# Find a projection that minizimizes residuals on multivariate regression

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, residuals, dimensionality-reduction, latent-variable

The problem I'm working on is from neuroscience. We've got multiple electrodes with weakly correlated noise all sampling the same system. What are using these to do autoregression on a latent 1D system. However, there are driving functions too. So we need a way to combine autoregression and latent factor discovery.

X
˙

σ
=
X
Ξ 
Where:
X is the N-D system timeseries (the electrode signals) 

X
˙
 is the 1st derivatve of the N-D system timeseries (the electrode signals). 
Ξ is the coefficient matrix. 
σ Projects to one dimension and is chosen to minimize the regression residuals.

**What are the ways that we can find σ? If we do PCA on the residuals will one of the columns from the projection matrix (loading matrix) be σ?**

The method will need to generalize to classic multiple regression where
Y
=
X
Ξ,
and the dimensionality of X is much greater than Y.

Comment: How are you defining "regression residuals"?  As a matrix with the same dimensionality of $X'$ or...?

Comment: Regression residuals: absolute value of the difference between the dependent variable and the prediction. There are two sets of residuals. If doing PCA on the residuals they're the same dimension as X'. But my goal is to get sigma which is a projection to one dimension. So the minimization objective is the residuals after projection. For now I'm ignoring goodness of fit measures (e.g. the l2 norm of residuals) because I'd guess not all methods will minimize the same goodness of fit measure. Note that I can apply sigma to both sides of the OLS equation.

Comment: You might also note that there are trivial solutions for sigma (zero vector). So any method would probably exploit some kind of full rank factorization of the residual matrix prior to projection. I think the minimum eigenvalue component of PCA would just be the subspace along which residuals cancel (anticorrelated), and not necessarily the subspace along which residuals are minimum.  So I might have asked a different question: what are the different ways to factorize the residual matrix and what do they mean?

Comment: That's a very interesting question... This looks to me like a (perhaps relative of a) canonical correlation problem:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation.  Does that seem right to you?

Comment: Yes at first blush that looks very similar I'll have to read a bit more. I also came across this question which is looking at the residuals but using diagnostics tests that don't do what I want. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/552585/residual-diagnostics-in-vector-autoregression-var-model vector Auto regression is basically what I'm doing and why I said that it would have to generalize to cases where the regressors have greater dimensionality. I'll be taking additional time lags and also nonlinear combinations of regressors.